# Accessing a 3rd party API JSON object in ruby

Tags: ruby, json

Been messing around with Kickbox's api for email verification. I'm trying to have the program only display the result object in the returned JSON.

Here's the code:

```
require "kickbox"
require 'httparty'
require 'json'


client   = Kickbox::Client.new('ac748asdfwef2fbf0e8177786233a6906cd3dcaa')
kickbox  = client.kickbox()
response = kickbox.verify("test@easdfwf.com")

file = File.read(response)

json = JSON.parse(file)

json['result']
```

I'm getting an error verify.rb:10:in `read': no implicit conversion of Kickbox::HttpClient::Response into String (TypeError)
    from verify.rb:10:in`'

Here's a sample response:

```
{
  "result":"undeliverable",
  "reason":"rejected_email",
  "role":false,
  "free":false,
  "disposable":false,
  "accept_all":false,
  "did_you_mean":"bill.lumbergh@gmail.com",
  "sendex":0,
  "email":"bill.lumbergh@gamil.com",
  "user":"bill.lumbergh",
  "domain":"gamil.com",
  "success":true,
  "message":null
}
```

Comment: Sorry - what is the desired output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error:

```
read': no implicit conversion of Kickbox::HttpClient::Response into String (TypeError)
```

Because, in this line:

```
file = File.read(response)
```

Your `response` is a `Kickbox::HttpClient::Response` type object, but the `File.read` is expecting a `String` object instead (possibly a file name with path).

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but this: `file = File.read(response)` is wrong. You can't do this and that's why you are getting the mentioned error.

If you really want to use file, then you can write the `response` to a file and then read the `response` back from the file and use that:

```
f = File.new('response.txt', 'w+') # creating a file in read/write mode
f.write(response) # writing the response into that file
file_content = File.read('response.txt') # reading the response back from the file
```

So, the issue is not about **Accessing a 3rd party API JSON object in ruby**, but you are trying to use `File.read` in a wrong way.

You can get the `response` from the API by doing this:

```
client   = Kickbox::Client.new('YOUR_API_KEY')
kickbox  = client.kickbox()
response = kickbox.verify("test@easdfwf.com")
```

Then, you can play with the `response` e.g. can do a `puts response.inspect` or `puts response.body.inspect` and see what's inside that object. 
And, from there you can extract your required outputs only.

Comment: Thanks this was super helpful! I'm trying to access the "result" object in the response